# Safely wrap JS files so when they are concatenated they still work

Tags: php, javascript, minify

I am using PHP to concat' several JS and CSS files.

The CSS is fine. The JS however breaks, but only some of the files break. I then stop these from being added and they then work again as individual files.

Is there a way I can safely wrap each files contents to ensure it will not break? And act "alone" to to speak?

I have tried some libraries to do this but haven't found anything reliable enough yet, hence the home brew.

Thanks
Jake

Comment: Are these files expected to work together? Do they share global variables? If not, it may simply be the case that global variables are overridden by other files. Should be easy to fix.

Comment: @Amaan No, they are not meant to. Some are my files and some are jQuery plugins.

Comment: Then you should probably do as jbabey's answer says and use IIFE's to prevent global variables (messing with each other).

Comment: @jakenoble: Does your concatenated file change the order of execution of the individual scripts? I.e. does jQuery or other dependencies get executed after a script that needs them?

Comment: No change in order. I made sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try wrapping the .js files into a function closure using php? i.e.

```
(function(){
  // file content
})();
```

I'm not sure if there will be unpredicted issues or not with your particular files, but you can try

Comment: I added a `;` to the end of each file and wrapped each with @Alex's code, it worked!

Answer (score 3):

In most of the cases some of the JS files lack a `;` at the end of the file.

As I'm pretty sure that is the issue, try to add after the function/s `;`

Comment: I guess adding an additional one will not hurt?

Answer (score 2):

You may be having problem with variable collisions. You can wrap all of your code for each file in their own scoped [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to prevent this.

Also, ensure that all of your javascript files have semicolons `;` at the last line of the file.

If you have a file ending like this:

`var foo`

And then the next file begins like this:

`var bar;`

When they're concatenated you'll have

`var foovar bar;`

which is not valid javascript.

Comment: If it were a name collision problem, wouldn't the scripts still not work as separate files? The only way I can think of where the concatenation would _trigger_ a name collision problem is if it changed the order in which the scripts were parsed, and the name collision simply doesn't have any negative effects in the original order that the browser parsed the scripts in.

Comment: The ordering is the same when concat' and when not.

Comment: @jakenoble: Then that is unlikely due to a variable name collision in the global namespace, as putting scripts in separate files does not put them in separate namespaces. All scripts loaded on a single page (in a single frame) share the same global namespace (unless you're using a module loader to load the scripts indirectly).